# How to ignore specific plugin versions in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Sometimes a specific version of a Jenkins plugin doesn't work at all because of a bug, or doesn't work in the context in which we use it.

I don't want to accidentally upgrade to such a Jenkins plugin version.

Is there somewhere I can specify 'do not use these specific plugin versions'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

However, for Jenkins 1.x, you can take a look at [pinned plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pinned+Plugins), which may make it easier to prevent accidentally overwriting an existing plugin. This feature was removed in Jenkins 2.

Comment: @Marnix, Note that pinning works only with plugins that are part of Jenkins distribution.

Comment: Thanks for these answers.  Is there perhaps an open [Jenkins JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS) issue for this functionality?  I couldn't find one, but perhaps I overlooked it...

Comment: Pinned plugins are no longer available in Jenkins 2.